# How to resolve sqlplus conflicts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, oracle, centos

I am install Oracle Instant Client: Basic, SDK and SQL*Plus packages v 12.1.0.1 for `gem "ruby-oci8"` than i realize that i need use Oracle Instant Client v 10.2.0.4. But whan i try to install  `rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-10.2.0.4-1.i386.rpm` i have error:

```
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    file /usr/bin/sqlplus from install of oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-10.2.0.4-1.i386 conflicts with file from package oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.1.0-1.i386
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to have two different versions of Oracle client libs (10g and 12c).
You can use:

- replace `-i` with `-U` (U stands for upgrade)
- remove ver. 10 first (`rpm -e`)
- If you insist on having two differt client versions remove .rpm packages. And use `.zip` packges. And simply unpack them into `/opt`

Comment: after that i have error  `sqlplus
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory` but i set ORACLE_HOME `env | grep ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/ what i need to do ?
`

Comment: ORACLE_HOME not only has to be "set" but also has to be "exported". You have to set and export variables "ORACLE_HOME" and also LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Then check the output from `ldd sqlplus` ldd `libclntsh.so`. Also check contens of `/etc/so.conf.d/` - the other way of setting library search path. I think this documented and least for .zip version of Oracle client libs.

Answer (score 0):

ldd sqlplus

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x006bf000)
    libsqlplus.so => /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib/libsqlplus.so (0x00110000)
    libclntsh.so.10.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1 (0x006c0000)
    libnnz10.so => /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib/libnnz10.so (0x00218000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x001c4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x001c9000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x0041e000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x00439000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00469000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x001f8000)
```

and  ldd libclntsh.so

```
ldd: ./libclntsh.so: No such file or directory
```

Comment: ORACLE_HOME does not have to be set, when using InstantClient. But you must have correct setting for library search path. Also you must not mix sqlplus and libs from different versions. And also must not mix binaries from InstantClient, Full client and the server.